# Black screen on startup on few minutes - amdgpu SMU issue

Tags: amdgpu, 22.10

When I boot my Ubuntu 22.10 I have a black screen for a few minutes. After this time my system starts.

In the logs I see many issues:
amdgpu 0000:0d:00.0: amdgpu: Failed to retrieve enabled ppfeatures!
amdgpu 0000:0d:00.0: amdgpu: SMU: I'm not done with your previous command: SMN_C2PMSG_66:0x0000000D SMN_C2PMSG_82:0x00000000

My VGA is:
lspci -nn | grep VGA
0d:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT] [1002:731f] (rev c1)

uname -a
Linux computer01 5.19.0-23-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct 14 15:39:57 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

This problem is described also on this site: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1886, but I don't now how to resolve it in my case.
Could you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What video driver do you have installed?

Comment: sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=3840,1080
       resources: iomemory:7c0-7bf iomemory:7e0-7df irq:154

Comment: @David : It says right in the kernel logs that those messages are coming from `amdgpu` module.  So it appears that the OP is using the Open Source `amdgpu`driver.